# Karate: Write to a text file

Tags: karate

I have the following feature file that reads the input and appends the input id with the response and writes to a text file in the below format:

```
 |123|{"products": [ { "pid": "1a"} ] }|
 |124|{"products": [ { "pid": "1b"} ] }|
 |125|{"products": [ { "pid": "1c"} ] }|
```

so that I can make the input table with it and dont need copy each response in text format and paste to make Examples:

I have tried the below:

```
Feature: sample karate test script
Background:
        * url BaseUrl
        * configure headers = read('classpath:headers.js')
        * def jsonFromCsv =  read('data.csv')
        * def size = karate.sizeOf(jsonFromCsv)
        * print size
Scenario Outline: Get All Tests
* def doStorage =
"""
function(args) {
  var DataStorage = Java.type('DataStorage.DataStorage'); // Java class that writes to a text file
  var dS = new DataStorage();
  return dS.write(args);
}"""

    Given path '/v1/path'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * def json = __row.expected
    * def id = __row.id
    * def app = '|'+<id>+'|'+json+'|'
    * print app # prinst it in the expected format
    * def result = call doStorage app   


Examples:
     | jsonFromCsv |
```

But the issue is only the last read data is being written to the file.
I had tried the below as well but gives the same result as above: 
`* def js = function (app){karate.write(app,'input.txt')}`

DataStorage.java:

```
package DataStorage;

    import java.io.*;

    public class DataStorage {
        public void write( String text) throws IOException {
           BufferedWriter output = null;
            try {
                File file = new File("input");
                output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                output.append(text);
                output.close();
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
              if ( output != null ) {
                output.close();
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to build Example tables from JSON?

Comment: Im trying to build the Example table for the regression suite.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it in a single shot.I have 1000+ test cases for a single API in an excel sheet to automate! likewise I have several services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSV files (have to be comma delimited): https://github.com/intuit/karate#csv-files

Also see this [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/dynamic-csv.feature):

```
Scenario Outline: cat name: <name>
    Given url demoBaseUrl
    And path 'cats'
    And request { name: '<name>', age: <age> }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match response == { id: '#number', name: '<name>' }

    # the single cell can be any valid karate expression
    # and even reference a variable defined in the Background
    Examples:
    | read('kittens.csv') |
```

Comment: I cannot use csv in my case because of character limit. API responses are more than the limit of csv so it will be truncated if we copy to csv. That's the reason I followed this approach

Comment: @JyothishKaimal I suggest you just create a JSON array and that is all you need. you can do this via Java and many teams integrate with a DB this way. look at this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features and then this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature - if you STILL have questions, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks@Peter. I came across another issue here the response json contains the array: `"Indicators": [
                    "A1","A2","A3","A4",
                ]`
But the issue is each time I hit the api the order of the array items changes, say

`"Indicators": [
                    "A2","A1","A3","A4",
                ]`
because of this match fails. Is there way to ignore the order of the array items? or how can I get this issue resolved?

Comment: @JyothishKaimal please don't call it an "issue" please read the docs and look for `contains`